# MySQL unknown column in ON clause not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
select orders.*
      ,customers.name as customername
      ,customers.city as customercity
      ,managers.name as managername
      ,godowns.name as godownname 
from orders
inner join customers 
inner join managers 
inner join godowns on orders.customerid=customers.customerid 
                   and orders.managerid=managers.managerid
                   and orders.godownid=godowns.godownid 
order by orderid desc;
```

I'm getting following error:

**Unknown column 'orders.customerid' in 'on clause'**

I have been bugging at this for over a day. It works in one system, not in another!

Comment: You're sure there's no schema difference between the two systems?

Comment: the schema is the same for both the systems. although i had to recreate the whole schema because the backup copy from my laptop didn't restore on my desktop due to syntax errors. Why would mysql produce syntax errors in its backups??

Comment: @SeanAllred - if you could, please tell me the difference so I can generate proper queries in my laptop and not scratch heads in front of my clients!!

Comment: I'm sorry :( I'm not really familiar with (most) dbms. It's just the first thing that popped into my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select orders.*,customers.name as customername,customers.city as customercity,managers.name as managername,godowns.name as godownname 
from orders 
inner join customers on orders.customerid=customers.customerid 
inner join managers on orders.managerid=managers.managerid 
inner join godowns on orders.godownid=godowns.godownid 
order by orderid desc
```

Every join needs an `on` clause

Comment: why does my query work in my laptop and not in my desktop?

Comment: No idea. Are you really sure you use the same query?

Comment: Yes, the same query, copy pasted to the full extent on the same database on a different server

Comment: if you could, please tell me the difference so I can generate proper queries in my laptop and not scratch heads in front of my clients!

Comment: If you write the joins as I did above then they will always work

Comment: yes they do, that's why i chose it as the best answer. But why does the wrong query work in one of the machines? Is there a fault in server configuration in that machine?

Comment: Like I said before, I don't know why. It should not work like that on any machine.